# Google Appengine Standard : Java8 Setting up Endpoints with IAP and ESP

Tags: google-app-engine, google-oauth, google-cloud-endpoints-v2

I am working on a web application that runs on Google Appengine and is able to be accessed from Android app that will synchronise some data from the server. I had this working smoothly until recent when I recreated the project on GCP and setup IAP, which works fine.

However, I am not able to configure the end point, where I keep getting **500 Server Error**. I have followed every step in this online instructions from Google https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/get-started-app-engine-standard and not able to figure out what am I doing wrong!!

Here are the contents of my files:

**Echo.java**

```
package com.example.endpoints;
import ...
@Api(
        name = "echo", 
        version = "v1",
        clientIds = { IAP_CREATED_WEBCLIENTID_FROM_CREDENTIALS, Constant.API_EXPLORER_CLIENT_ID},
        audiences = {IAP_CREATED_WEBCLIENTID_FROM_CREDENTIALS}, 
        namespace = @ApiNamespace(
                ownerDomain = "com.example.endpoints", 
                ownerName = "com.example.endpoints", 
                packagePath = "")
)

public class Echo {

  @ApiMethod(name = "echoonly", path = "/echo/v1/echoonly")
  public Entity echoonly() {      
    Entity testingResponse = new Entity("TestingResponse", 1000000L);
    testingResponse.setProperty("name", "Only");
    return testingResponse;
  }

  @ApiMethod(name = "echoname", path = "/echo/v1/echoname/{name}")
  public Entity echoname(
        @Named("name") @Nullable String name) {     
    Entity testingResponse = new Entity("TestingResponse", 1000000L);
    testingResponse.setProperty("name", name);
    return testingResponse;
  }

  @ApiMethod(name = "echoage", path = "/echo/v1/echoage/{name}/{age}")
  public Entity echoage(
        @Named("name") String name, 
        @Named("age") String age) {     
    Entity testingResponse = new Entity("TestingResponse", 1000000L);
    testingResponse.setProperty("name", name);
    testingResponse.setProperty("age", age);        
    return testingResponse;     
  }
}
```

**pom.xml** (partial only which I think are relevant here...)

```
<groupId>endpoints</groupId>
<artifactId>endpoints</artifactId>
<properties>
    <endpoints.project.id>MYCLOUDRUNSERVICENAME-HASHCODE-uc.a.run.app</endpoints.project.id>
    <appengine.maven.plugin.version>2.3.0</appengine.maven.plugin.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <maven.compiler.showDeprecation>true</maven.compiler.showDeprecation>
    <endpoints.framework.version>2.2.1</endpoints.framework.version>
    <endpoints.management.version>1.0.4</endpoints.management.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>...</dependencies>
<build>
   <plugins>...</plugins>
</build>
```

**appengine-web-.xml**

```
<threadsafe>true</threadsafe>
<sessions-enabled>false</sessions-enabled>
<service>default</service> <!--  THIS IS USED TO UPLOAD TO A SPECIFIC SERVICE. REMOVE THIS FOR DEFAULT -->
<runtime>java8</runtime>

<system-properties>
    <property name="java.util.logging.config.file"
        value="WEB-INF/logging.properties" />
</system-properties>

<env-variables>
    <env-var name="ENDPOINTS_SERVICE_NAME" value="${endpoints.project.id}" />
</env-variables>
```

**web.xml**

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>EndpointsServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.google.api.server.spi.EndpointsServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>services</param-name>
        <param-value>com.example.endpoints.Echo</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>EndpointsServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/_ah/api/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<filter>
    <filter-name>endpoints-api-configuration</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.google.api.control.ServiceManagementConfigFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter>
    <filter-name>endpoints-api-controller</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.google.api.control.extensions.appengine.GoogleAppEngineControlFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>endpoints.projectId</param-name>
        <param-value>${endpoints.project.id}</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>endpoints.serviceName</param-name>
        <param-value>${endpoints.project.id}</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>endpoints-api-configuration</filter-name>
    <servlet-name>EndpointsServlet</servlet-name>
</filter-mapping>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>endpoints-api-controller</filter-name>
    <servlet-name>EndpointsServlet</servlet-name>
</filter-mapping>
```

**deployendpoint.yaml**

```
swagger: '2.0'
info:
  title: MyEndPointTestApi771  API
  description: Sample API on Cloud Endpoints with a Cloud Run, Cloud Function and App Engine with IAP backend
  version: 1.0.0
host: MYCLOUDRUNSERVICENAME-HASHCODE-uc.a.run.app
basePath: /_ah/api
schemes:
  - https
consumes:
 - application/json
produces:
  - application/json
x-google-backend:
  address: https://MYPROJECTID.uc.r.appspot.com
  jwt_audience: IAP_CREATED_WEBCLIENTID_FROM_CREDENTIALS
x-google-allow: all
paths:
  /echo/v1/echoonly:
    post:
      summary: echoonly
      operationId: EchoEchoonly
      responses:
        '200':
          description: A successful response
          schema:
            $ref: "#/definitions/Entity"
      security:
      - google_id_token: []
  /echo/v1/echoname/{name}:
    post:
      summary: echoname
      operationId: EchoEchoname
      parameters:
        - in: path
          name: name
          required: true
          type: string        
      responses:
        '200':
          description: A successful response
          schema:
            $ref: "#/definitions/Entity"
      security:
      - google_id_token: []
  /echo/v1/echoage/{name}/{age}:
    post:
      summary: echoage
      operationId: EchoEchoage
      parameters:
        - in: path
          name: name
          required: true
          type: string
        - in: path
          name: age
          required: true
          type: string        
      responses:
        '200':
          description: A successful response
          schema:
            $ref: "#/definitions/Entity"
      security:
      - google_id_token: []
       
definitions:
  _any: 
    type: "object"
  Entity:
    type: "object"
    properties: 
      appId: 
        type: "string"
      key: 
        $ref: "#/definitions/Key"        
      kind: 
        type: "string"        
      namespace: 
        type: "string"        
      parent: 
        $ref: "#/definitions/Key"        
      properties: 
        $ref: "#/definitions/Map_String_Object"        
      propertiesFrom: 
        $ref: "#/definitions/Entity"        
  Map_String_Object: 
    type: "object"
    additionalProperties: 
      $ref: "#/definitions/_any"      
  JsonMap: 
    type: "object"      
  Key: 
    type: "object"
    properties: 
      appId: 
        type: "string"    
      complete: 
        type: "boolean"    
      id: 
        type: "integer"
        format: "int64"    
      kind: 
        type: "string"    
      name: 
        type: "string"    
      namespace: 
        type: "string"    
      parent: 
        $ref: "#/definitions/Key"

securityDefinitions:
  api_key:    
    type: "apiKey"
    name: "key"
    in: "query"
  google_id_token:
    authorizationUrl: 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?client_id=IAP_CREATED_WEBCLIENTID_FROM_CREDENTIALS&response_type=code&scope=openid%20email&access_type=offline&redirect_uri=urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob'
    flow: "implicit"
    type: "oauth2"
    x-google-issuer: "https://accounts.google.com"
    x-google-jwks_uri: "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/certs"        
    x-google-audiences: "IAP_CREATED_WEBCLIENTID_FROM_CREDENTIALS"
```

**Update**
I could not figure this out and went with Spring @RestController which worked perfect, without having to worry about creating Endpoints API on Google Cloud Platform

Comment: Did you verify that your service accounts have the right permissions :) ?

Comment: Default Compute Service Account is given access as IAP-Secured Web App User by running this command `gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding MY_PROJECT_ID  --member "serviceAccount:MY_PROJECT_NUMBER-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com"  --role "roles/iap.httpsResourceAccessor"` from the instructions from Google page mentioned in my question. Is there any other service account I need to add access to as well?

Comment: Check your logs in your cloud console.  What is the traceback for the 500 error say?